# Flutter custom icons are not showing in Android studio

Tags: flutter

I am trying to add a custom icon into one of my `buttons` in my Flutter app.

- I have included the `ttf` file inside my `fonts` folder in my project directory
- I have also included the icon's `dart` file into my `lib` folder in my project directory
- This is my **pubspec.yaml**:

[image]

- This is my **lib**:

[image]

- My flutter code where I am implementing the icon:

```
Container(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  width: double.infinity,
  child:ElevatedButton.icon(
    onPressed: () {},
    icon: const Icon( // <-- Icon
      MyFlutterApp.send
    ),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.purple,
    ),
    label: Text('Fetch records'), // <-- Text
  ),
)
```

- This is my output button:

[image]

I don't have a single clue as to why my icon shows as a (X). Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

in your pubspec.yaml try removing the name of your images and just give the directory of your images, like this:

```
assets:
   - images/
```